# I mistakenly forgot to keep my laptop plugged in while updating it.Will my laptop be okay?

Tags: windows-update

My laptop had to be restarted for a Windows Update.While restarting I forgot to keep the A/C adapter plugged into my laptop.Will my laptop be harmed in any way?

Comment: It should be fine, as long it didn't shut off during updating, and you now have it plugged in ...

Answer (score 4):

If the battery completely runs out while the laptop is not plugged into the A/C, then the laptop will shut down.  If it's in the midst of a normal session (you can see the desktop) then it's a small problem : you will lose unsaved documents, but any Windows Update process will be fixable.

With Windows Updates, if interrupted during the Restart phase, it's possible for the OS installation to be left in an inconsistent state.  Sometimes, the machine can just pick up where it was, sometimes, you can run a repair.  Sometimes, you have to save whatever documents you can and reinstall the OS.

With BIOS updates or firmware updates, then it's possible for the whole PC to be broken and be unbootable.  Definitely only perform BIOS or firmware updates with the PC plugged into the wall.